# iPhone doesn't connect to wifi unless the laptop is ON

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, home-networking, connection

I always thought that there was something wrong with my wireless home wifi. It connects to all the computers, printer and laptops wirelessly but NOT my iphone. Till just recently, i noticed that my iphone actually connects to the home wifi ONLY when my laptop is switched ON!
has anyone encountered such a problem before? 
what can i do so my iphone simply connects to the home wireless wifi without having me to switch the laptop on each time 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a quite strange issue. I would see a reason why turning on the laptop would prevent the iPhone from connecting (duplicate ip, for example). But the opposite? Strange. On your question, try to add more details. What kind of router, is there a matter of distance to router involved, which channel is the wifi using, this kind of things.

Comment: It sounds like you have set your iphone to connect to your laptop as an access point instead of the router.  You have not given us enough information.  Its possible to treat and setup a Windows 7 laptop with a wireless 800.11 device as an access point ( trivial really ).

Comment: I guess you have already tried to reset the WiFi-Settings on your iPhone? Also check, if the iPhone appears on the list of connected devices on your router, when it seems to be connected.

Answer (score 1):

As is stated in the comments, it sounds like you have set the iphone to connect to your laptop.

Here's my suggestion on how to resolve it.

- Make sure your laptop is on
- Go into settings --> Wi-Fi
- Click on the Blue Arrow, next to the connected network
- Choose Forget this network
- Shut down your laptop
- Reconfigure your iphone, to use your wi-fi network.

The key is to forget the old network, and shut down your laptop, to prevent the same mistake that happened last time.